# Random variable or number?

Tags: probability, random-variables

We have the common probability distribution of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ :

[image]

At the terms: $$Y, \ y_j, \ E(Y), \ E(Y\mid X), \ E(Y\mid X=x_i), \ E_X(E(Y\mid X))$$ is just $Y$ a random variable and all the others are numbers?

Answer (score 1):

$Y$ is defined as a random variable.  You have not defined $y_j$, but if it is the $Y$ value from the $j^{th}$ draw of $X,Y$ it is a number.  All the expectations are numbers that are computed from your probability table except $E(Y|X=x_i)$ which is a function of $x_i$.

Comment: So, it $E(Y\mid X=x_i)$ not a number? Is this a random variable?

Comment: As I said, it is a function of $x_i$.  If $x_i=2, E(Y|X=2)=\frac 12$ and so on.  It can't be a number because it depends on $x_i$.  You can compute its distribution, so you could call it a random variable.